# Variables dont change to "int" - stuck at "str"

Tags: python

In my program I need to make simple math calc, but my variables are defind at `str` and i need to make it `int` for the calc and sum .

ex:

When age=40, in return I got 404040404040 (6 times the num 40)
is read the res like "str" and I need "int".

```
def check_age(age):
    age = int(age)
    return 30 * 6 if age >= 30 else 0


def just_married():
    sum_married = 0
    woman_age = int(input("Please enter the wife age [we know that is not ok ask woman about she's age] : ").strip())
    sum_married = sum_married + check_age(woman_age)
    husband = int(input("Please enter the husband age : ").strip())
    sum_married = sum_married + check_age(husband)
    return int(sum_married)


def children_age(number_of_children):
    sum_children = number_of_children*50
    return int(sum_children)


def work_hard():
    print("for WIFE - Are you working part-time (0.5) or full-time (1)? : ")
    wife_work = input()
    print("for HUSBAND = Are you working part-time (0.5) or full-time (1)? : ")
    husband_work = input()
    sum_work = (wife_work+husband_work)*75
    return int(sum_work)


def main():
    sum_func = 0
    print("The following is a program aimed at examining eligibility conditions "
          "for participation in the tender Housing for the occupant.")
    sum_func += just_married()
    print("How many children over the age of 18 do you have? : ")
    children = input()
    sum_func += children_age(children)
    sum_func += work_hard()
    program_number = 599
    if sum_func > program_number:
        print("you got : " + str(sum_func) + " points ")
    else:
        print("sorry, but you need " + str(program_number-sum_func) + " point to join the program. try next time.")


main()
```

edit:
i edit the code, with the new change at func"check_age", and update the full code.

this is the input :

```
The following is a program aimed at examining eligibility conditions for participation in the tender Housing for the occupant.
Please enter the wife age [we know that is not ok ask woman about she's age] : 40
Please enter the husband age : 50
How many children over the age of 18 do you have? : 
4
for WIFE - Are you working part-time (0.5) or full-time (1)? : 
1
for HUSBAND = Are you working part-time (0.5) or full-time (1)? : 
1
you got : 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111155555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555915 points 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `input(int)` must be `int(input())`.

Comment: This part of the code ```new_age=30*6``` must be ```new_age=int(age)*6```, and then you need to return ```str(age)```, if you expect a string in return.

Comment: The only multiplication in this code is `new_age=30*6`, which is clearly integer multiplication, so I don't see how the claimed problem of string multiplication can even occur.

Comment: Can you show us children_age and work_hard method?

Comment: `int()` doesn't *change* the type of an object. It just returns a *new* object of type `int` (if it can be converted to an int)

Answer (score 1):

In your function `check_age`:

```
def check_age(age):
    age = int(age)
    return 30 * 6 if age >= 30 else 0
```

Also, consider changing these lines:

```
print("Please enter the wife age [we know that is not ok ask woman about she's age] : ")
woman_age = input(int)
```

To this:

```
woman_age = int(input("Please enter the wife age [we know that is not ok ask woman about she's age] : ").strip())
```

Explanation:

- `input` takes a string, prints it and wait for user input.
- `str.strip` removes trailing spaces
- `int` convert a variable to an integer

Once you've sanitized your inputs, you can remove the explicit conversion to int in `check_age`:

```
def check_age(age):
    return 30 * 6 if age >= 30 else 0
```

[EDIT] A few more suggestion:

- create a function `sanitize_input` that takes a text, ask for input
  ad returns an integer. Then use it anywhere to replace `print`...`input`
- create logic blocks that make sense: For example, the main function contains all the texts that print out to the screen and store all inputs for later. Then, only process the variables in one function like `check_eligibility` or something where you do all the calculations. If you do that, you code will be more understandable and less error prone, for you and for the people who try to help you

Comment: hey,
i think i dont understend all of what you wirt here .. ;-\
i have change the func : check_age, and the sum is wrong.
i input 2 number's:
wife(40),husband(50), its give me : 360 and the ans for this should be 540...

and one more thing, i dont understand how i make int variables and not str.

thanks for the help !!

Comment: I just rewrote your original function word for word and removed the useless stuff. If the result is wrong, then your original function was wrong. Since I don't know what you want to do, I did not correct the logic...
For the data types, I suggest you read [this](https://realpython.com/python-data-types/)

Answer (score 0):

The string -> number conversions have to be done *before* you attempt any calculations, it is too late at the time of `return`, as the strange things have happened already. Remember/learn that Python can add strings (which is common to many languages, `"1"+"1"` is `"11"` in various other languages too), and on top of that, it can also multiply them with integer numbers, `"1"*5` is `"11111"`.
If you assume correct input from the user, the simplest thing is to do the conversion in the `input` lines, which already happens in `just_married`, but not in the other places.
And of course remember that when you expect an input like `0.5`, those should be converted to `float`.

```
def check_age(age):
    #age = int(age)                          - removed this one, should happen at input
    return 30 * 6 if age >= 30 else 0

def just_married():
    sum_married = 0
    woman_age = int(input("Please enter the wife age [we know that is not ok ask woman about she's age] : ").strip())
    sum_married = sum_married + check_age(woman_age)
    husband = int(input("Please enter the husband age : ").strip())
    sum_married = sum_married + check_age(husband)
    return sum_married                       # removed int(), it is already an integer

def children_age(number_of_children):
    sum_children = number_of_children*50
    return sum_children                      # removed int(), it was too late here
                                             # and it should happen at input


def work_hard():
    print("for WIFE - Are you working part-time (0.5) or full-time (1)? : ")
    wife_work = float(input())               # added float()
    print("for HUSBAND = Are you working part-time (0.5) or full-time (1)? : ")
    husband_work = float(input())            # added float()
    sum_work = (wife_work+husband_work)*75
    return int(sum_work)                     # int() may stay, depending on what should happen
                                             # with fractions - they are just thrown away now

def main():
    sum_func = 0
    print("The following is a program aimed at examining eligibility conditions "
          "for participation in the tender Housing for the occupant.")
    sum_func += just_married()
    print("How many children over the age of 18 do you have? : ")
    children = int(input())                  # added int()
    sum_func += children_age(children)
    sum_func += work_hard()
    program_number = 599
    if sum_func > program_number:
        print("you got : " + str(sum_func) + " points ")
    else:
        print("sorry, but you need " + str(program_number-sum_func) + " point to join the program. try next time.")

main()
```

Comment: ok, i understand what you saying about (*)str ("1"+"1"="11"), but when i change the code to what you do, its work, and i dont understand where was the problem with the code :-(

Comment: @idan, ok, an example: in the original `work_hard`, `wife_work` was a string, say `"1"`, `husband_work` was another string with `"1"`, and then `(wife_work+husband_work)*75` produced `"11"` as the sum, and repeated it 75 times, that is how the result was 150 digits long, mainly consisting of `1`-s.